# Variavel dentro da Requisição GET Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, get

Boa tarde, estou precisando de uma ajuda, eu tenho essa requisição get do ajax que envia para o web service, e preciso colocar essa variável id, na url, pois dentro do webservice eu pego essa variável e trato o retorno, correto ? acontece que ao colocar a variável concatenando na url não consigo nenhum resultado o retorno que obtenho é "undefined", se eu colocar um valor estático por exemplo um numero: url: "http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/users-update/55/update" então eu consigo ter o retorno como 55, o que preciso fazer para que a variável seja reconhecida ? Obrigado.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        var id;


       $.getJSON('http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/users-list-all',function(data){
                 $.each(data, function(k, v){

                   id = v.iduser;
                   console.log(id);

                    });
              });

     $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/users-update/"+id+"/update",
            method: 'GET',
            data: JSON,
            success: function ( response ) {
              console.log(response);
              console.log(id);

              $.each(JSON.parse(response), function(k, v){


                  $("#desperson").attr("value",v.desperson);
                   $("#deslogin").attr("value",v.deslogin);
                    $("#nrphone").attr("value",v.nrphone);
                    $("#desemail").attr("value",v.desemail);
                     $("#inadmin").attr("value",v.inadmin);


              });


               /*window.location.replace("http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/users/users-update")*/
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, o método **$.getJSON** é assíncrono.
Ou seja, você acaba utilizando o id no método **$.ajax** antes de o método anterior setar um valor para a variável ID.
Tenta fazer um **$.ajax** com parâmetro **async: false** no lugar do **$.getJSON**, desse modo, o segundo método **$.ajax** não é iniciado antes do término do primeiro.

Tenta substituir o **$.getJSON** todo por:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/users-list-all',
    async: false,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(k, v){
            id = v.iduser;
            console.log(id);
        });
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```

Ou com tudo assíncrono, note que o AJAX 2 só roda no caso de sucesso do AJAX 1, desse modo não é preciso a variável global ID, ela é local:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/users-list-all',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var id;
            $.each(data, function(k, v){
                id = v.iduser;
                console.log(id);
            });

            //Segundo AJAX
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/users-update/"+id+"/update",
                method: 'GET',
                data: JSON,
                success: function ( response ) {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(id);

                    $.each(JSON.parse(response), function(k, v){
                        $("#desperson").attr("value",v.desperson);
                        $("#deslogin").attr("value",v.deslogin);
                        $("#nrphone").attr("value",v.nrphone);
                        $("#desemail").attr("value",v.desemail);
                        $("#inadmin").attr("value",v.inadmin);
                    });
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log('Erro AJAX 2: ' + error);
                }
                //Fim do segundo AJAX
            });
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log('Erro AJAX 1: ' + error);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: hmm entendi, estranho que coloquei um console.log na resposta e ele vem com o valor do id dentro mesmo do ajax, mas você teria como me enviar um exemplo de como ficaria com esse parametro false ?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, tentai ai

Comment: Consegui aqui cara deu super certo, era isso mesmo que precisava, estava amarrando tudo via session, pegando agora o ID vai ficar muito mais facil, só tem uma coisa eu só recebi esse log : jquery.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: Certo! Agora você vai precisar colocar um $.ajax dentro da propriedade success do outro! Assim você tira o async: false, vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: Beleza estou aguardando Valeu !

Comment: Vish o unico erro que deu o primeiro console.log do primeiro ajax e o segundo tráz outro id, estou tentando descobrir o porque.

Comment: Tenta colocar as aspas em data: JSON por data: 'json'

Comment: eu descobri aqui o get ta pegando sempre o mesmo id ao que parece tenho que ver por que, estranho que a primeira vez que executou deu certo.

Comment: Esquece descobri aqui kkkkkk Orelhada minha auhahuahuahuahu